# Regexp match time expression (mmmm:ss)

Tags: regex

I have an application where I want to check time input. Allowed forms for minutes(m, anything from 0-9999) and seconds(s, between 0-59) are:

```
s
ss
m:ss
...
mmmm:ss
```

and my current regexp I have is:

```
^([0-9]){0,4}(?=\:)\:?([0-5]){0,1}([0-9]){1}|([0-5]){0,1}([0-9]){1}$
```

which matches all of the above, but I would NOT expect it to match

```
:ss
```

While it is not critical for me to NOT match the last `:ss` I wonder: Why does it match the last (and how would you suggest I modify my regexp for it to exclude that case)?

Comment: By the way, `(?=\:)\:?` means: "check there is definitely a colon on the next position, and optionally match a colon". In effect, it is the same as `:`. `{0,1}` is the same as `?`, and `{1}` does nothing. You also don't need parentheses around character classes (unless you want to capture the last digit) - `([0-7]){0,4}` -> `[0-7]{0,4}`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing those things out. While I am not entirely new to regular expressions I certainly consider myself to be learning still :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?:\d{1,4}:)?[0-5]?\d$
```

Were, we only match a colon (`:`) if we matched at least one digit earlier. Your patterns allows a colon with no numbers in front of it, so your text can start with it.

Working example: http://rubular.com/r/rFROIed8Pg

A trickier option is `^\b\d{0,4}:?[0-5]?\d$` - this makes both the colon and the minutes optional, but would not match the colon at the beginning of the string.

---

Some additional explanation about the comment:

To disallow `mmm:s` (single second digit), one possible pattern is:

```
^(?:\d{1,4}:(?=\d{2}))?[0-5]?\d$
```

A quick explanation:

- The end is simple: `[0-5]?\d$` - 0-59
- The first part is trickier:

  - `\d{1,4}:` - Match one to four digit and a colon.
  - `(?=\d{2})` - But only if the colon is followed by two digits! This is a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) - it will fail if there is only one digit after the colon.

Comment: This one is great, and so much more elegant than my expression. One problem though, it passes `123:1` as well as `123:9`. I guess my question implies it, but I didn't really appreciate the face myself: If number + colon are found, the part after the colon has to be 2 digits. I am playing around with the tester (ty for the link!) but so far couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @kontur - In that case you can use `^(?:\d{1,4}:[0-5]\d|[0-5]?\d)$`, or a little trickier again: `^(?:\d{1,4}:(?=\d{2}))?[0-5]?\d$`

Comment: Pretty amazing. The first one of those I can wrap my head around, but in the second one you completely lose me :D Could I ask you to put the second regexp into words; I'd love to understand what exactly it does and how?

Answer (score 1):

this says to match

```
^([0-9]){0,4}(?=\:)\:?([0-5]){0,1}([0-9]){1}
```

OR

```
([0-5]){0,1}([0-9]){1}$
```

try this instead

```
^([0-9]){0,4}(?=\:)\:?([0-5]){0,1}([0-9]){1}|:?([0-5]){0,1}([0-9]){1}$
```

Comment: Ah okay, somehow I assumed the `^` and `$` to be unaffected by the `|`, but the OR seems a bit out of place either way :)

Comment: then you can group it using `( ... )` or `(?: ... )` if you want a non-capture group